# building aspectj BETA_JAVA8

Tags: ant, build, aspectj

im trying to build aspectj from source. it appears that one of the tools included in aspectj is a ajdoc which is a replacement for javadoc. unfortunately the build is failing at this stage. ive narrowed it down to the fact that the current javac task is not including tools.jar in its classpath.

```
  [ajbuild] C:\Development\workspace\org.aspectj\ajdoc\src\org\aspectj\tools\ajdoc\JavadocRunner.java:27: error: package com.sun.tools.javadoc does not exist
  [ajbuild]                     Class jdMainClass = com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.class;
  [ajbuild]                                                              ^
  [ajbuild] C:\Development\workspace\org.aspectj\ajdoc\src\org\aspectj\tools\ajd
```

is it possible to force ant's javac's task to include a given jdk's tools.jar?

Answer (score 0):

building aspectj through ant version of eclipse solved the classpath issues